# Energy Loss of a Ball which Splits into Pieces

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction, collision

It is well-known that one can analyse the loss of kinetic energy when an inelastic ball falls and bounces back up from the ground in terms of the coefficient of restitution

$$E_f - E_i= \frac{K_i - K_f}{K_i}   \; = (1-e^2)   \;,$$

where $e$ is the coefficient of restitution.

What happens if the ball is bouncing back up and then splits into several pieces which continue moving?  Does each piece have the same kinetic energy that the ball had as a whole when it was bouncing back up?

I guess my question is more generally, if an object is moving and then breaks up into pieces, what happens with the kinetic energies of the pieces compared to that of the original object?

Comment: Does each piece have the same mass as the original ball?

Comment: No, so each piece hjas some mass which is a fraction of that of the orignal ball.

Comment: Maybe you meant to ask if the _sum_ of the kinetic energies of all of the fragments would be the same as the kinetic energy of the ball before it split?

Comment: I guess that is a related question.  The ball is bouncing and then moving up, then is splits up.  Is the sum of the kinetic energies of all the fragments the same as the KE of the ball before splitting, or is there energy lost due to the splitting procedure etc.?

Comment: Could be energy gained from splitting. Depends on what split it.

Comment: I am thinking of for example, the impact causes cracks to go through a macroscopic object so that it splits into pieces on the way back up.

Comment: So, if hitting the pavement cracks the ball, that's probably going to use up most of the kinetic energy that it built up on the way down. I can't imagine what it would have to be made of in order to break when hitting the ground, but still have enough energy for the pieces to bounce back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does each piece have the same kinetic energy that the ball had as a whole when it was bouncing back up?

No. Each different peace has only fraction of mass from original monolithic ball. Hence, assuming that ball mass is distributed uniformly between it's peaces,
$$ \frac {\Delta K}{K_0} = \sum_n \frac {\Delta K_n}{K_0} = \frac {\sum_n \Delta K_n}{K_0}  = n\frac {\Delta K_{p}}{K_0}  \tag 1$$

Where $K_0$ is full ball kinetic energy before collision, $\Delta K_{p}$ - single part kinetic energy deficit, $n$ - number of parts.

Comment: If the kinetic energy of each piece is smaller than that of the original ball, will the speed of each piece also be smaller?

Comment: No. Kinetic energy of peace is reduced due to reduced mass of peace compared to the original object, as kinetic energy $K=mv^2/2$. Imagine a train is riding at $300~km/h$ with just 1 wagon. Say wagon & locomotive has mass of $29~tons$ each. So train has $\approx 200~MJ$ kinetic energy. Now at some point while driving, train operator uncouples the wagon, so locomotive & wagon now has kinetic energy of $100~MJ$ each. But speed of separate parts of train does not reduce instantly due to uncoupling (it may later reduce for wagon due to friction). Same here, speed same of parts as of ball.